# ¿Qué diferencia hay al colocar o no paréntesis en la creación de clases?

Tags: python, poo

**¡Hola comunidad!**

Ésta es una pregunta bastante teórica. He notado en diversos códigos que algunos programadores tienden a colocar paréntesis "()" cuando crean una determinada clase mientras que otros obvian estos caracteres.

Ejemplo:

```
class MiClase1():
    pass

class MiClase2:
    pass
```

¡Gracias de antemano por sus comentarios!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La diferencia es ninguna, ambos son exactamente lo mismo, los paréntesis en éste caso se usan para implementar la herencia, por lo tanto entre ellos van la clase padre o clases padre de las que nuestra clase deriva.

A diferencia de lo que ocurre en la definición de funciones/métodos, en éste caso son totalmente opcionales.

En tus ejemplos no se deriva de ninguna clase explícitamente, por lo que ambas declaraciones son exactamente los mismo.

```
class Foo: # Solo deriva de object
    a = 3

class Bar(): # Solo deriva de object
    b = 5

class FooChild(Foo): # Deriva de object y de Foo
    c = 7

class FooBar(Foo, Bar): # Deriva de object, de Foo y de Bar
    d = 13

print(FooBar.a, FooBar.b, FooBar.c)
```

Realmente en Python 3 toda clase deriva de la clase `object`, la cual sirve de base para cualquier otra clase y de la cual se derivan métodos esenciales para la implementación correcta de nuestra clase como `__new__` o `__getattribute__`.

Personalmente, tiendo a no ponerlos cuando la clase no deriva de nada y se supone que es la forma preferible de hacerlo, pero ningunas de las dos formas es incorrecta en cuanto a sintaxis, ni hay diferencias internas alguna.

Hay que tener en cuenta que los paréntesis que se usan cuando una clase se instancia no tienen nada que ver con los  paréntesis anteriores:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(a, b):
        self.suma = a + b
```

Al hacer:

> ```
> >>> instancia = Foo(3, 5)
> ```

los paréntesis son los que permiten generar la instancia, son lo que ponen en marcha toda la maquinaria para generar un nuevo objeto de la clase, llamando a `__new__` y después a `__init__`. Lo que se pasa entre los paréntesis en este caso son argumentos para el inicializador (`__init__`) de la clase.

> ```
> >>> print(instancia.suma)
>   8
> ```